# android: crop specific portion of a view

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to convert a specific `view` (`UI`) into an image (eg. `jpeg` or `png`)... to achieve this i have thought to crop view through programming. I have come across many good links over here, but all of them deal with Bitmap or photo itself. Please guide me with a clue to achieve this effect.
Please find the attached screenshot below.

[image].

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the answer:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```